# How to create a ToolStripMenuItem with several controls on it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Such as a Label and a TextBox.

I tried:

```
class MyClass : ToolStripPanel
{
      //...
}
```

And the like. But then:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new MyClass());
```

shows an error:

> ...invalid arguments.

Comment: No. It's not "totally incorrect". It's overloaded.

Comment: You can add a ToolStripPanel control directly to your ContextMenuStrip, and then add controls to the ToolStripPanel - is that what you want to do? There isn't really a need to inherit directly from the ToolStripPanel class.

Comment: @dash This: `contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripPanel());` fails the same way.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - it's been a while since I've done this. You can use the ToolStripControlHost class - I can give you an example if you want?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [ToolStripControlHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx) class to host any Windows Forms control on a ContextMenuStrip (or indeed any of the Strip controls)

For example, the following code will add a label to a context menu strip:

```
    Label newlabel = new Label();
    newlabel.Text = "Hello World";
    newlabel.Width = 300;
    ToolStripControlHost tsHost = new ToolStripControlHost(newlabel);

    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(tsHost);
```