# How to add Controls, as a toolbar, to a ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripitem

I'm making a Web Browser, but I don't know how to add these buttons on top of its ContextMenuStrip:

[image]

A Sepator make columns for all items, but no for only one line.
Do you have any idea how to make that?

Comment: Use [ToolStripControlHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033785/how-to-create-a-toolstripmenuitem-with-several-controls-on-it).

Comment: It make controls in one line :(

Answer (score 3):

Here's a custom Component, inheriting [ToolStripControlHost](http://ToolStripControlHost) (as the .Net's [ToolStripTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstriptextbox), [ToolStripComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox) etc.) that hosts a UserControl instead of a standard Control.

▶ Building a UserControl, you can add whatever other Controls to its surface and manage their actions as usual, except the UserControl's Events are exposed through the `ToolStripControlHost` derived object, so implementers don't need to know anything about the underlying hosted Control.

The hosted Control's events that you want to expose are subscribed to overriding [OnSubscribeControlEvents()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.onsubscribecontrolevents) (and of course unsubscribed to overriding [OnUnsubscribeControlEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.onunsubscribecontrolevents)), then raising a related or *composed* event that returns values as needed.

▶ This is shown in the `ToolStripControlHost` class, see the `public event EventHandler<UserActionArgs> ButtonAction` event. This event returns a custom `EventArgs` object which includes properties that allow to determine the action performed by the Button clicked.

When needed, the hosted Control is exposed through the [ToolStripControlHost.Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.control) property.

---

You can initialize an existing ContextMenuStrip (`contextMenuStrip1`, here) in the constructor of the Form that uses it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ToolStripUserControl toolStripUC = new ToolStripUserControl();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Assigns an existing ContextMenuStrip, to the Form or any other Control
        this.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;

        // Inserts the ToolStripUserControl and a Separator
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(0, new ToolStripSeparator());
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(0, toolStripUC);

        // Subscribes to the ButtonAction event
        toolStripUC.ButtonAction += (s, e) 
            => { this.Text = $"Your Action is {e.UserAction}, triggered by {e.TriggerControl.Name}"; };
        contextMenuStrip1.Closed += (s, e) => this.Text = "Right-Click on me";
    }
}
```

**`ToolStripControlHost` derived class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class ToolStripUserControl : ToolStripControlHost
{
    // Pass the UserControl, MenuStripNavigationBar, to the base class.
    public ToolStripUserControl() : base(new MenuStripNavigationBar()) { }

    public MenuStripNavigationBar NavigatorBar => Control as MenuStripNavigationBar;

    // Exposes the ButtonActions Dictionary, to redefine the Buttons' actions
    public Dictionary<Control, ButtonAction> ButtonActions {
        get => NavigatorBar.ButtonActions;
        set => NavigatorBar.ButtonActions = value;
    }

    // Subscribe to the events you want to expose...
    protected override void OnSubscribeControlEvents(Control ctl)
    {
        base.OnSubscribeControlEvents(ctl);
        var navigatorBar = (MenuStripNavigationBar)ctl;
        navigatorBar.UserAction += OnButtonAction;
    }

    // ...and then unsubscribe. This is called when the Form is destroyed
    protected override void OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(Control ctl)
    {
        base.OnUnsubscribeControlEvents(ctl);
        var navigatorBar = (MenuStripNavigationBar)ctl;
        navigatorBar.UserAction -= OnButtonAction;
    }

    // Exposes a public custom event
    public event EventHandler<UserActionArgs> ButtonAction;

    // Raises the event when an UserAction is triggered
    private void OnButtonAction(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctl = sender as Control;
        var userAction = new UserActionArgs(ButtonActions[ctl], ctl);
        ButtonAction?.Invoke(this, userAction);
    }
}
```

**Custom EventArgs object**:

```
public class UserActionArgs : EventArgs
{
    public UserActionArgs(ButtonAction action, Control control)
    {
        UserAction = action;
        TriggerControl = control;
    }
    public ButtonAction UserAction { get; }
    public Control TriggerControl { get; }
}
```

**Actions enumerator**:

```
public enum ButtonAction
{
    MoveBack,
    MoveForward,
    PlayMusic,
    PlayAnimation
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: ToolStripControlHost UserControl]

This is the full UserControl, to ease testing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MenuStripNavigationBar : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler UserAction;

    public MenuStripNavigationBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonActions = new Dictionary<Control, ButtonAction>();

        buttonArrowLeft.Text = "⏪";
        ButtonActions.Add(buttonArrowLeft, ButtonAction.MoveBack);
        buttonArrowLeft.Click += ButtonsActionEvent;

        buttonArrowRight.Text = "⏩";
        ButtonActions.Add(buttonArrowRight, ButtonAction.MoveBack);
        buttonArrowRight.Click += ButtonsActionEvent;

        buttonMusicKey.Text = "♬";
        ButtonActions.Add(buttonMusicKey, ButtonAction.PlayMusic);
        buttonMusicKey.Click += ButtonsActionEvent;

        buttonAction.Text = "⛄";
        ButtonActions.Add(buttonAction, ButtonAction.PlayAnimation);
        buttonAction.Click += ButtonsActionEvent;
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public Dictionary<Control, ButtonAction> ButtonActions { get; set; }

    private void ButtonsActionEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        => UserAction?.Invoke(sender, e);


    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    internal class ButtonPanel : Panel
    {
        private Color borderActiveColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        private Color borderInactiveColor = Color.Gray;
        private Color borderColor = Color.Transparent;

        public ButtonPanel()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | 
                          ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.StandardClick, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
            OnEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
            OnLeave(e);
        }

        protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnEnter(e);
            bool hovered = ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition));
            borderColor = hovered ? Enabled ? borderActiveColor : borderInactiveColor : Color.Transparent;
            Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(MousePosition))) return;
            borderColor = Color.Transparent;
            base.OnLeave(e);
            Invalidate();
        }

        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | 
            TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine;

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            var textRect = Rectangle.Inflate(ClientRectangle, 0, -1);
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, Text, Font, textRect, ForeColor, Color.Empty, flags);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle, borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
        }
    }
}
```

Designer file:

```
partial class MenuStripNavigationBar
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null)) {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonAction = new MenuStripNavigationBar.ButtonPanel();
        this.buttonArrowLeft = new MenuStripNavigationBar.ButtonPanel();
        this.buttonArrowRight = new MenuStripNavigationBar.ButtonPanel();
        this.buttonMusicKey = new MenuStripNavigationBar.ButtonPanel();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonAction
        // 
        this.buttonAction.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.buttonAction.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.buttonAction.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(166, 2);
        this.buttonAction.Name = "buttonAction";
        this.buttonAction.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 26);
        this.buttonAction.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // buttonArrowLeft
        // 
        this.buttonArrowLeft.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.buttonArrowLeft.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.buttonArrowLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 2);
        this.buttonArrowLeft.Name = "buttonArrowLeft";
        this.buttonArrowLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 26);
        this.buttonArrowLeft.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // buttonArrowRight
        // 
        this.buttonArrowRight.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.buttonArrowRight.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.buttonArrowRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 2);
        this.buttonArrowRight.Name = "buttonArrowRight";
        this.buttonArrowRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 26);
        this.buttonArrowRight.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // buttonMusicKey
        // 
        this.buttonMusicKey.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.buttonMusicKey.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.buttonMusicKey.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 2);
        this.buttonMusicKey.Name = "buttonMusicKey";
        this.buttonMusicKey.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 26);
        this.buttonMusicKey.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // MenuStripNavigationBar
        // 
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonMusicKey);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonArrowRight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonArrowLeft);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonAction);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(212, 30);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(212, 30);
        this.Name = "MenuStripNavigationBar";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(212, 30);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private ButtonPanel buttonAction;
    private ButtonPanel buttonArrowLeft;
    private ButtonPanel buttonArrowRight;
    private ButtonPanel buttonMusicKey;
}
```