# Multiple buttons in toolStripMenuItem .NET WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-standard, toolstripmenu

I'm working in C# Windows Form .NET standard and I would like to create a menustrip with multiple buttons like the one in figure, I don't even know how it is called.

[image: example]

Comment: You can look at the `ToolStripControlHost` class and host a custom control.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65280439/14171304) as `UserControl` + `ToolStripControlHost` example. Or, create a custom `ToolStripMenuItem`.